# HTML Email Client Border Removal

Tags: css, html-email

Ok, so I'm trying to create a simple as you like single column html email template.

The issue that I'm having is that I can not seem to get rid of the white boarder that surrounds the message when I paste the html code into my email client to sent a test message.

I've set the css of the `body`to an inline and this works perfectly when I test in the browser, there is no white boarder or margin....

```
    <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #000000" bgcolor="#000000">
```

....but when I come to paste the code into the mail client (I use Mac Mail as my default) to send a test mail, I keep getting a white boarder all around the message and CAN NOT work out how to get rid of this.

I've looked at an html email that I received with full width background color and tried to work out what that does that I'm not but can't see anything different, so am I just missing something real simple here??

```
<html>

   <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"> <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->

        </head>

            <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" bgcolor="000">

                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#999999" border-collapse="collapse">
                    <tr>
                        <td   align="center">
                            <table width="100%" height="200" bgcolor="#ffffff;" class="respon_table" style="max-width: 650px; padding: 10px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">Email content goes here....</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q16jgdtr/

[image: this is the white border, the grey doesn't go the edge on either side]

Comment: You're posting html with classes in it. As an example, `respon_table` You're not posting the classes. Please post your entire code, from `<html>` to `<html>` so we can see why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled `bgcolor` attributes. It should be a valid color.
E. g. `bgcolor="#ffffff;"` should be `bgcolor="#ffffff"` -- without a semicolon.
And `bgcolor="000"` should be `bgcolor="#000000"`.

https://jsfiddle.net/q16jgdtr/3/

https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it's because you missed the following on the table that contains the contents of the email.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#999999" border-collapse="collapse">
 <tr> 
        <td align="center"> 
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" height="200" bgcolor="#ffffff;" class="respon_table" style="max-width: 650px; padding: 10px;" border-collapse="collapse"> 
               <tr> 
                     <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">Email content goes here....</td>
               </tr>
               </table> 
          </td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
```

I have added border collapse, cellpadding, cellspacing and border to zero. Give the above code a try, hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: hi @Syfer thanks for the reply, but it doesn't fix my issue.  I've uploaded a screen shot showing the white border around the <table> element which in the browser is 100% width of the screen but in the email client never seems to be.  Mac Mail never seems to let me get the full width

Comment: Did you try the fix asked/recommended by Kosh Very?

Comment: Yes I applied the changes to my syntax that Kosh suggested